# How to Update a table while joining another table

Tags: sql, join, sql-update

I know how to join these two tables (invoices and payables). Payables has a `balancedue` column and I need to make that the same as `Invoices.originalamount`.

What I have written is:

```
update payables p
set p.balancedue= i.originalamount
From payables p
join invoices i on p.id=i.id
where nationalaccountcode='xxx'
```

But i'm getting an error. Any help? SSMS 2012, if that helps.

Comment: I think you're looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
UPDATE Payables 
    SET balancedue = i.originalamount
FROM invoices i
WHERE nationalaccountcode='xxx' AND Payables.id = i.id
```